# ReactJS popup Screen doesn't take 100% of body

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, modal-dialog, styled-components

I have a child functional component which displays items. I wanna add item to the list on pop up screen. I have added logic to make it 100% but it doesn't work. I am using styled components.

I have tried doing `height: 100%; width: 100%`

```
export const MainContainer = styled.div`
  height: 110vh;
  width: 110vw;

  /* padding: 20px 24px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-20%, -62%);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; */
  
`;
```

Doing "100vh or 100vw" reserves the space of size 100vh (full screen height) but still shows after the other div component.

I tried using react-modal, but I can't style it . If you know how to custom style a modal compnent. Please let me know.

[Clicking Add item make this appear out of the propertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh797.png)

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with styled components or react. It just seems to be a question about CSS...

Comment: You could use `position: fixed` ...

Comment: @Dominik Actually, I am not quite sure if it's coming form CSS or styled components. I was not really sure what's causing this. I checked lot of stack overflow question, they suggest using fixed position with height: 100vh, issue is still persistent. Additem component is still being pushed down. I am gonna add image.